# How to get org mode file "Title" and other file-level properties from an arbitrary file?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I have files with this format

```
#+TITLE: Magit Cheatsheet
:PROPERTIES:
:Status: Open
:Tags: tools, emacs, org, magit
:Creation: [2021-03-03 Wed]
:END:
```

I'd like to be able to read the title and these properties for a given file name (not the currently open file) with elisp. I found [this](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/27620/orgmode-capturing-original-document-title) but it isn't working for me and seems too complex for something as simple as this.

Comment: The contents you show above is not a legal Org mode file. Do `M-x org-lint` to see why. There are two problems: the `:PROPERTIES:` drawer is only legal under a headline (there are [other ways to define properties at the top level](https://orgmode.org/manual/Property-Syntax.html#Property-Syntax)); and there is a [special property](https://orgmode.org/manual/Special-Properties.html#Special-Properties) called `TAGS` that Org mode uses internally (and the case does not matter), which conflicts with your `Tags` property.

Comment: @NickD Has this changed? I seem to recall seeing something about a file-level properties drawer that was due to be release..?

Comment: Yes, this went into 9.4: see [ORG-NEWS](https://code.orgmode.org/bzg/org-mode/src/master/etc/ORG-NEWS) - currently at line 594 of the file, but that is likely to change. And `org-lint` needs to be updated to recognize this possibility.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot answer the question about the properties until you fix the file (how you fix it will affect the proposed solution).

For the title however, the following code works (Q: what is the shortest lie in computing? A: It works!):

```el
#+begin_src elisp :results drawer
  (defun ndk/get-keyword-key-value (kwd)
     (let ((data (cadr kwd)))
       (list (plist-get data :key)
             (plist-get data :value))))

  (defun ndk/org-current-buffer-get-title ()
      (nth 1
       (assoc "TITLE"
        (org-element-map (org-element-parse-buffer 'greater-element)
            '(keyword)
            #'ndk/get-keyword-key-value))))

  (defun ndk/org-file-get-title (file)
    (with-current-buffer (find-file-noselect file)
         (ndk/org-current-buffer-get-title)))

  (ndk/org-file-get-title "/tmp/foo86.org")
  #+end_src
```

The main function is the last one `ndk/org-file-get-title` which takes care of opening the file and running the `ndk/org-current-buffer-get-title` function on the resulting buffer. The latter functions uses the almighty `org-element-map` function on a subset of the data that the parser returns (that's for efficiency only): we map the `ndk/get-keyword-key-value` function on all the keyword elements. This function returns a `(key value)` list for each of the keywords that it gets called on, and the mapper accumulates those pairs into a list. We then select the pair that contains the string "TITLE" as the key, and the `(nth 1 ...)` call gets the value part of the pair (the key part would be `(nth 0 ...)`).

A minor variation of this would also work for dealing with  `#+PROPERTY` keywords, but dealing with property drawers under a headline would be more complicated (I think - I haven't tried it out).